# Why are these FactoryGirl factory instances not being created to pass this index test?

Tags: capybara, factory-bot, factory

I am trying to test presence of all model objects in an index view, index renders just fine with manual in browser use, so the problem must be with with my FactoryGirl factory and or the way I'm passing arguments into the `FactoryGirl.create` method, though research fails to reveal to me what exactly I'm doing wrong, any ideas? Thanks

`quotes.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quote do
    prev_cover true
    sequence(:co_name) { |n| "Acme Co #{n}" }
    co_number 9999
    postcode "al1 1aa"
    industry :financial_services
    lives_overseas true
    scheme_start_date "2018-01-01"
    payment_frequency :monthly
    commission_level 12
    gla 1

    factory :quote2 do
    end

    factory :quote3 do
    end
  end
end
```

quotes_page_spec.rb

```
    require 'rails_helper'

feature 'index page' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }    
    let(:quote) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co1") }
    let(:quote2) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co2") }
    let(:quote3) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co3") }

    before do
        login_as(user, :scope => :user) 
    end

    scenario 'when user view all their quotes' do
        visit("/quotes")
        expect(page).to have_content("Co1")
        expect(page).to have_content("Co2")
        expect(page).to have_content("Co3")
    end
```

This is the failure message i get;

```
 1) index page when user view all their quotes
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Co1")
   expected to find text "Co1" in "Toggle navigation QuoteEngine My Quotes My Account Sign out"
 # ./spec/features/quotes_page_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Also you don’t need to register factory quote2 and quote3, just call `create(:quote, ...` multiple times

Comment: Question body updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you’re using `let`.  `let` is lazily evaluated, so the object is not actually created until the first time it is referenced in the test.  Since you never reference the quote objects in your test they are never created.  To have the objects always created use `let!` rather than `let`

Comment: Any reason why `let!` might be preferable to writing a `before` block, or visa versa?

Comment: Not really, but sticking to one or the other for your test object creation makes it clearer for anyone reading your tests in the future.  The biggest difference is that `let/let!` produce local methods for accessing the objects (`quote`) vs needing to use instance variables in before blocks (`@quote`) if you need to access the element in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Error was that I was not actually creating the multiple quotes by declaring them as `let`s. Moved the quotes that I want to be created into a before block and all is well, as below:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }    

before do
    login_as(user, :scope => :user) 
    FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co1")
    FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co2")
    FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user, co_name: "Co3")
end
```

Comment: Rather than moving the creates, just change the `let` instances to `let!` as mentioned in my answer. Keeping your test object creations in one place (all let/let! or all in a before, rather than splitting into multiple types) makes tests easier to read